# getting upgrade pip warning but requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, pip, warnings, upgrade

I have started a fresh venv in a new project location and after activating it used `pip list` to see what a fresh venv included. The listing included a warning that I was not using the latest version of pip:

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 23.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '<path to project>/venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

However, when I execute the recommended command I get another warning that the requirement is already satisfied:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (23.2)
```

which just hangs there forever until I kill it.

What am I missing here? Is this a PATH conflict and it might be looking elsewhere in my environment?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just uninstall pip then ensure it in order to re-download an updated version.

```
<path to project>/venv/bin/python3 -m pip uninstall pip
<path to project>/venv/bin/python3 -m ensurepip
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.  Meanwhile, it did eventually upgrade pip without the warning, without me doing anything, so I'll just keep this in mind for the next occurrence.

Answer (score -1):

Is this a PATH conflict and it might be looking elsewhere in my environment?
Yes it is. Can you try uninstalling pip and reinstalling it again. Also check your system paths to make sure everything is okay

https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+check+system+path+windows&oq=how+to+check+system+path+windows&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB7SAQkxNzAwNmowajSoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The path ../`venv/bin/` doesn't look like Windows, it's more likely Linux. On Windows the path would be `..\venv\Scripts`

Comment: This was on Mac OS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).